# Is there anyway to tell which fields are grouped fields in a MySQL result (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code that will run user-generated SQL on a MySQL table. The query possibilities are limited, but could be, for example

```
SELECT City, Country, count(*) FROM Table ... GROUP BY City, Country
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) AS Count, Role, Country FROM Table ... GROUP BY Role, Country
```

or

```
SELECT count(*), TicketType, City, SUM(Quantity) AS 'Total Quantity' FROM Table ... GROUP BY TicketType, City
```

and so on.

When presenting the results of the query, I want to take one type of action if the column is an grouped field (e.g. COUNT or SUM or AVG etc.)

Other than parsing the query, is there any way to determine which fields are grouped fields from the result set? I am using mysqli and PHP

Comment: Unparsed, user-generated SQL?  What a **brilliant** idea!  Good luck.

Comment: Restricted commands, not unparsed and run as a separate (limited access) user on a separate database that is generated on the fly before the user SQL is run.

Comment: I assumed "*unparsed*" because you said "*other than parsing the query...*".   Even so, you don't know what the resultset means and so cannot know how it should be handled (which is the fundamental problem underlying your question).  This is bad, BAD, **BAD**, ***BAD*** design.  Don't do it.  Ever.

Comment: I agree with you in general terms, but there are specific scenarios in which what is normally considered bad design is actually quite OK and this is one of them - I haven't given full detail on how it all works, because it is not relevant to the question at hand. For a specific, well accepted example of where user generated SQL is acceptable, look at phpmyadmin ...

Comment: phpMyAdmin (and similar tools) are agnostic to the *meaning* of the resultset.  They don't care what the results mean.  They don't need to know whether a column has been aggregated or not.  Clearly your application requires greater insight into the semantics of the datasets that it is handling, which requires it (at very least) to parse the queries that generate them - but if it is to handle the resultsets in any way, then to maintain any certainty over their semantics I would *very strongly advise* you to decompose the user's request and reassemble it before sending to the database.

Comment: As I said above, it is not unparsed SQL. I do check it very carefully before allowing to reach the (isolated) database, but I appreciate your concern. Also, phpMyAdmin is not completely agnostic to the meaning of the SQL - if you have a DROP statement, it checks if you really want to run the SQL... I don't know if it has intelligence for the resultset too, but I can see how it might be a nice feature to have that for some things!

Comment: I don't get it, then.  If you are parsing the SQL, you would already know on which columns the results are grouped?

Comment: I am not parsing it to look for that, I am parsing it to check that it contains only specific characters or commands. It would make more design sense to determine which columns are the grouped ones from the resultset metadata, if that information is available through mysqli, hence my question. As it seems it is not, then I will do it as part of the parsing.

Comment: Then you're not parsing the SQL at all, you're merely pattern matching it.

Comment: Perhaps a poor choice of words on my part then, but to me pattern matching is a type of parsing. No matter!

Answer (score 0):

it is simple I guess, the only fields you can select in SELECT clause are the fields that are either grouped in Group By clause or grouped by aggregated functions.

So when you use

`SELECT City, Country, count(*) FROM Table ... GROUP BY City, Country`

your result set will have multiple rows each with three columns:city,country,count(*). city and country are the fields which are grouped by.

Comment: But I need to programmatically determine where the count(*) field is. It could be the first, second or third column. There may be a count and sum field and it may be renamed (using AS). I can do it via parsing, I am wondering if there is something in the result set somewhere that indicates it is one of the grouped fields.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is no.
What you receive from the db are field names and values. Without parsing the original query you can't be sure which fields are aggregations and which are not.

Probably in your case there can be constraints you can use. For example:

- If numbers can be only generated fields you can check the contents of the result. (Of course this is very unstable.)
- Maybe you can use the field's name as a hint. Maybe it contains something related to aggregations. (sum, count, total,...)

But probably to best/most stable way to handle your problem to get more control around the query generation, and set explicit constraints you need or save the details you need later.

Maybe you can try to use this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php
But I don't think it will be satisfying.